# Easy use of native IDispatch* as .NET object possible?

Tags: .net, com, c++-cli

In a c++/clr dll (.net 4.5), is it possible to create a .NET object from a native IDispatch* (or IUnknown*, its a dual-interface COM object)? I don't want to register the COM object but I can get a pointer to it via c call from another dll. But how can I use this pointer to create a .net object (generated via "add reference..." from tlb)? I mean, without calling Invoke etc. directly.

Answer (score 0):

ok now I found the solution by myself. [Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getobjectforiunknown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is what I was looking for. That was probably too easy to ask here...?